# iPhone, iPad script rule out

Tags: iphone, ipad, load

Is it possible to rule out a script load only when viewing site on Apple devices? For example I don't want this file to be loaded on iPhone/iPad:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.skinned-select.js"></script>
```

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) // check for touch screen 
{ }
else {
// run code for mouse device

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    s.setAttribute("src", "js/jquery.skinned-select.js");
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var node = nodes[nodes.length - 1].parentNode;
    node.appendChild(s);
};
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't bring any effect. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: Strange,  I had the same problem yesterday and that's how I solved it.  I forgot to say that you should delete 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.skinned-select.js"></script>

Comment: That did it! Thanks, you've helped mi a lot.